# On click event on any known word

Tags: javascript, html

I have a paragraph with some text like

> "This is a bad paragraph. The good things is, this is bad. Do you know what is the bad side of it? Very bad, why you do not know this."

How can I fire an event on click any of the "bad" word. without replacing the 'bad' word by `<span class="good-class">bad</span>` or anything else ?

Comment: Transform every word in the paragraph into an anchor.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry I have made a mistake. Question has edited.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible using only selectors. Since selectors select entire elements.
But, you can do little trick here as:

```js
var $el = $(".my-text"),
    html = $el.html();
   
// Replace with spans
html = html.replace(/\b(bad)\b/ig,"<span class='bad-text'>$1</span>");
// Update content 
$el.html(html);

// Assign click handler to those new elements
$(".bad-text").on("click", function(e) {
  alert(this.textContent);
});
```

```css
.bad-text{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="my-text">
Bad! This is a bad paragraph. The good things is, this is bad. Very bad, why you do not know this. Simbad is a badass
</p>
```

First replace the word 'bad' with some selector and then bind that selector.

Comment: you should also make notice that the regex you used (/bad/g) will not replace "Bad" and will also make part of "Simbad" clickable...

Comment: yeah! that's right...
thanks for pointing out.
But seeing his current text, I wrote the regEx.
If user tells his exact requirement, how text is gonna be.. will change that also.
Based on your input, made a new change.

Comment: You're welcome! :) But Nitesh, the only *good* improvement you made in your *improved* [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zo2tx0y/1/) is that now you account for the case insensitive `i`... A hint: you need only one `.replace` not  3 (or even more...) . Another novice hint: use capturing groups `()` and refer than to the match using `$1`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I took you suggestion, studied little more about RegEX and made a better change.
Please check by 3rd fiddle. Do you think it should be OK?
Once again, thanks sir!

Comment: Nice to see your improvements! You were close. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6zo2tx0y/3/ - Consider to update your Answer

Comment: Now the fun part is that OP actually in not interested at all into replacing the content with `<span>` which makes your answer useless after all :D

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that you could get the innerHTML of the element and then put spans around the text that says 'bad' and add an eventListener to them. Of course if you have access to the html, you could just put spans around them to begin with.

Select your paragraph in the DOM, either by Id or TagName or something - it's hard to tell you which without the original html.

Then replace the word 'bad' with 'bad', next access all those spans and add event listeners to them. Inside the event listener do a double check that the span contents is 'bad', then do whatever code you want.

```
var el = document.getElementById("this-text");
var text = el.innerHTML;
var newText = text.replace(/\bbad\b/g, "<span>bad</span>");
el.innerHTML = newText;
var spans = el.getElementsByTagName('span')
for (let i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.innerHTML === 'bad') {
      alert('You clicked bad') // put whatever you want here
    }
}, false);
}
```

Also here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/attg0zqz/

Comment: OP is aware but not interested into `<span>` replacements - (P.S./BTW: your example replaces only lowercase `bad`)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Apparently so, although the OP has edited their question. There was no mention of not including spans when the question was first posted. (Also, the OP can do what they like with the replacement, but the question only mentions lowercase 'bad')